# Como continuar setInterval despues de haberlo parado

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Con el primer boton quiero parar el intervalo y en la segunda parte continuar el intervalo, pense que desde donde se quedo el incremento podria continuar luego... Y ahora ni siquiera se para el primer intervalo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <title>Objeto Window</title>
 <meta charset="UTF8"/>
 <body>
  <p>El intervalo que sucede cada 1.000 milisegundos se ha repetido <span id="tiempo">0</span> veces.</p>
  <button onclick="pararIntervalo()">Parar el intervalo</button>
  <button onclick="continuarIntervalo()">continuar el intervalo</button>

 </body>

 <script>

 let miIntervalo = setInterval(

  function(){
   miTemporizador()
  },1000);

  let incremento = 0;

  function miTemporizador() {
   incremento++;
   document.getElementById("tiempo").innerHTML = incremento;
  }

  function pararIntervalo() {
   clearInterval(miIntervalo);
  }



  let miIntervalo2 = setInterval(

   function(){
    continuarIntervalo()
   },1000);

   function continuarIntervalo() {
    incremento++;
    document.getElementById("tiempo").innerHTML = incremento;
   }


</script>

</head>

</html>
```

Comment: Esa funcionalidad deberías implementarla tú. Un `clearInterval` elimina el timer creado por `setInterval`, no existe la posibilidad de parar y continuar.

Answer (score 3):

Trato de explicarte las opciones que tienes:

**OPCION 1 - Set Interval + variable que acumula**

> Con `setInterval` siempre que quieras borrarlo, lo perderás.
>
> Más adelante, tienes un ejemplo de código donde lo que se hace, es llamar a una función dentro del Interval que guarda el valor de segundos acumulados cuando lo paramos, en la variable `window.count`.
>
> Si se para el intervalo, se resetea el `window.count` por lo que se vuelve a comenzar desde cero.

**OPCION 2 - setTimeout en vez de setInterval**

> Lo que se suele hacer en estos casos, es aprovechar setTimeout (que no se repite eternamente), y enlazar un método con otro en cadena. Puedes ver la solución que han dado en [este link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3969760/3617531).
>
> `setTimeout` es un método que sólo se ejecuta una vez, por lo que
>   envolverlo en una estructura de código que "lo repite" es también una
>   forma de conseguir lo que quieres.

Te pego aquí el [código de la solución 1](http://www.overclock.net/t/1354355/javascript-start-stop-pause-button-for-setinterval):

```js
var pause=0;
var count=0;
var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); 
var stoped=0
function timer()
{
  count=count+1;
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count + " secs"; 
}

function StopFunction()
{
  clearInterval(counter);
  window.count=0;
  window.pause=0;
  document.getElementById("pause").innerHTML="Pause"
  window.stoped=1
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count + " secs";
}

function ReStartFunction()
{
  if (counter)
  {
    clearInterval(counter);
    window.pause=0;
    window.count=0;
    window.stoped=0
    window.counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); 
    count=count+1;
    document.getElementById("pause").innerHTML="Pause"
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count + " secs"; 
  }
}

function PauseFunction()
{
  if (stoped==0)
  { 
    if (pause==0) 
    {
      clearInterval(counter);
      document.getElementById("pause").innerHTML="Resume"
      pause=1;
      return;
    }

  if (pause==1) 
    {
      window.counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); 
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count + " secs"; 
      document.getElementById("pause").innerHTML="Pause"
      pause=0;
      return;
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Con startTimeout puedes pararlo y arrancarlo </p>
<p id="timer"></p>

<button onclick="ReStartFunction()">ReStart</button>
<button onclick="StopFunction()">Parar</button>
<button id="pause" onclick="PauseFunction()">Pausa</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Te adjunto también [otro link donde explican más opciones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30427882/make-a-timer-using-setinterval)

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71123/discussion-on-answer-by-alejandro-teixeira-munoz-como-continuar-setinterval-desp).

Comment: En que tenga un momento, la mejoro y añado el otro modo. El link original lo estoy buscando. Y el chat no me deja responder, no se por que ...

Comment: corregido. PD: El link, en efecto era de donde @Pablo dijo. Confundí uno con otro de los que estuve mirando. Perdón N veces por el error.

Comment: Perfecta edición.

Comment: Pablo, disculpa decirte que el código no era de ahí. Trasteando me lié de pestaña y estaba totamente convencido. Mea culpa

Answer (score 1):

modifiqué tu código y cree una variable global que la usaré como intevalo, y otra con el contador y luego inicio el intervalo o le hago clear...

Prueba el siguiente código:

```
<script>

// init de intervalo
var incremento = 0;
var intervalo;
var myIntervalo;

// comienza conteo
 myIntervalo = setInterval(function(){

    incremento++;
    document.getElementById("tiempo").innerHTML = incremento;

}, 1000);



// detengo intervalo
function pararIntervalo() {

    clearInterval(myIntervalo);

}

// retomo intervalo
function continuarIntervalo(){

    myIntervalo = setInterval(function(){

       incremento++;
       document.getElementById("tiempo").innerHTML = incremento;

   }, 1000);

}


</script>
```

Saludos y nos cuentas como te fue!